# Custom made widget not showing in Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress

I just made a custom widget myself, I'm able to see it in the widget area but I can't find it in the editor using Visual Composer plugin. Is there anything wrong within my widget? My widget simply uses this example as provided by Wordpress.org:

```
    /**
 * Adds Foo_Widget widget.
 */
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'foo_widget', // Base ID
        __( 'Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
        array( 'description' => __( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
}

/**
 * Front-end display of widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::widget()
 *
 * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
 * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

            echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
    }
    echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}

/**
 * Back-end widget form.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::form()
 *
 * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
            $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
}

} // class Foo_Widget
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must create dedicated for visual composer Here is example

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Extend Visual Composer Plugin Example
Plugin URI: http://wpbakery.com/vc
Description: Extend Visual Composer with your own set of shortcodes.
Version: 0.1.1
Author: WPBakery
Author URI: http://wpbakery.com
License: GPLv2 or later
*/

/*
This example/starter plugin can be used to speed up Visual Composer plugins creation process.
More information can be found here: http://kb.wpbakery.com/index.php?title=Category:Visual_Composer
*/

// don't load directly
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) die('-1');

class VCExtendAddonClass {
    function __construct() {
        // We safely integrate with VC with this hook
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'integrateWithVC' ) );

        // Use this when creating a shortcode addon
        add_shortcode( 'bartag', array( $this, 'renderMyBartag' ) );

        // Register CSS and JS
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'loadCssAndJs' ) );
    }

    public function integrateWithVC() {
        // Check if Visual Composer is installed
        if ( ! defined( 'WPB_VC_VERSION' ) ) {
            // Display notice that Visual Compser is required
            add_action('admin_notices', array( $this, 'showVcVersionNotice' ));
            return;
        }

        /*
        Add your Visual Composer logic here.
        Lets call vc_map function to "register" our custom shortcode within Visual Composer interface.

        More info: http://kb.wpbakery.com/index.php?title=Vc_map
        */
        vc_map( array(
            "name" => __("My Bar Shortcode", 'vc_extend'),
            "description" => __("Bar tag description text", 'vc_extend'),
            "base" => "bartag",
            "class" => "",
            "controls" => "full",
            "icon" => plugins_url('assets/asterisk_yellow.png', __FILE__), // or css class name which you can reffer in your css file later. Example: "vc_extend_my_class"
            "category" => __('Content', 'js_composer'),
            //'admin_enqueue_js' => array(plugins_url('assets/vc_extend.js', __FILE__)), // This will load js file in the VC backend editor
            //'admin_enqueue_css' => array(plugins_url('assets/vc_extend_admin.css', __FILE__)), // This will load css file in the VC backend editor
            "params" => array(
                array(
                  "type" => "textfield",
                  "holder" => "div",
                  "class" => "",
                  "heading" => __("Text", 'vc_extend'),
                  "param_name" => "foo",
                  "value" => __("Default params value", 'vc_extend'),
                  "description" => __("Description for foo param.", 'vc_extend')
              ),
              array(
                  "type" => "colorpicker",
                  "holder" => "div",
                  "class" => "",
                  "heading" => __("Text color", 'vc_extend'),
                  "param_name" => "color",
                  "value" => '#FF0000', //Default Red color
                  "description" => __("Choose text color", 'vc_extend')
              ),
              array(
                  "type" => "textarea_html",
                  "holder" => "div",
                  "class" => "",
                  "heading" => __("Content", 'vc_extend'),
                  "param_name" => "content",
                  "value" => __("<p>I am test text block. Click edit button to change this text.</p>", 'vc_extend'),
                  "description" => __("Enter your content.", 'vc_extend')
              ),
            )
        ) );
    }

    /*
    Shortcode logic how it should be rendered
    */
    public function renderMyBartag( $atts, $content = null ) {
      extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'color' => '#FF0000'
      ), $atts ) );
      $content = wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content, true); // fix unclosed/unwanted paragraph tags in $content

      $output = "<div style='color:{$color};' data-foo='${foo}'>{$content}</div>";
      return $output;
    }

    /*
    Load plugin css and javascript files which you may need on front end of your site
    */
    public function loadCssAndJs() {
      wp_register_style( 'vc_extend_style', plugins_url('assets/vc_extend.css', __FILE__) );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'vc_extend_style' );

      // If you need any javascript files on front end, here is how you can load them.
      //wp_enqueue_script( 'vc_extend_js', plugins_url('assets/vc_extend.js', __FILE__), array('jquery') );
    }

    /*
    Show notice if your plugin is activated but Visual Composer is not
    */
    public function showVcVersionNotice() {
        $plugin_data = get_plugin_data(__FILE__);
        echo '
        <div class="updated">
          <p>'.sprintf(__('<strong>%s</strong> requires <strong><a href="http://bit.ly/vcomposer" target="_blank">Visual Composer</a></strong> plugin to be installed and activated on your site.', 'vc_extend'), $plugin_data['Name']).'</p>
        </div>';
    }
}
// Finally initialize code
new VCExtendAddonClass();
```

Comment: Thanks @Grek .. I'm able to see a widget inside Visual Composer Backend Editor. It would be more helpful if you also provide a short explanation to this.

Comment: You have explanation in code.  You can configure block  and get this config values on render. Render function is renderMyBartag here you must return some html.

Comment: @GregHmhmm I am trying to create a container but I am getting an error for creating class inside class.. the error seems to occur where I have `if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) { class WPBakeryShortCode_Your_Gallery extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer { } }` Where do I have to place that code?